# How to update a value at specific position in cell data

Tags: r, readxl, writexl

I have an excel sheet. Where I have data like this

```
Sample_d   sample_normal
1          (0.234,0.889)
```

I want to remove the '()' brackets from the first and last positions in the 'sample_normal' column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the data into R and then use :

```
df <- readxl::read_excel('excel_file.xlsx')
df$sample_normal <- gsub('^\\(|\\)$', '', df$sample_normal)
```

Comment: Wow! it works. Thank you. Can you please recommend to me any book or website where can I learn the basics of R? especially working with excel sheets.

Comment: Advanced R is a good book for general R. https://adv-r.hadley.nz/